# Confused about a few lines code in a scala official document page

Tags: scala

In this document page: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html

I saw the following sample code:

```
class EdgeImpl(origin: Node, dest: Node) {
    def from = origin
    def to = dest
}
```

It looks strange to me that 'def' should normally be used to define a method, but here why are the 'from' and 'to' assigned with 'Node' objects?

Can anyone confirm whether it's an error in the document page or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: They are both methods that just return `origin` and `dest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from` and `to` *are* methods in class `EdgeImpl`. They both have zero parameters and a return type of `Node`. `from` isn't "assigned" the value of `origin` per-se. It's just a method that always returns `origin`.

Without reading too much into it, it can probably have just been made a `val`, but a method that returns a constant value is completely valid.

Answer (score 2):

A method definition in scala looks like

```
def methodName(param1: ParamType, param2: ParamType): ReturnType = { methodBody; return foo }
```

Now, keeping in mind that return type ascription, and keyword `return` are optional, and so are curly braces (if the whole body of the method consists of a single statement), and parameter lists (if there are no parameters), does it help?

Someone with a java background and an aversion to novelty, could have written those functions like

```
def from(): Node = { return origin; }
```

which is (almost) equivalent, but less idiomatic, and harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's an error on the page:

Consider this line below:

```
def from = origin
```

What's the return type of that method? It's `Node` - so, what does this tell you? It simply means that it's a getter method in the class `EdgeImpl`. This is a very common convention in Scala for writing getters.

You might argue that it's confusing to find getter methods being "assigned" to some object and that it should *explicitly* say that it's a getter method with an empty `()`. The simple rule of hand is: It's perfectly fine to have parameterless methods where there's no side-effect happening. But if you need no-param methods (the ones with `()`), it's usually used where there's a chance of a side-effect occurring, like writing to a file or maintaining a mutable state and so on.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I think they should be parameterless methods.

> A parameterless function is a function that takes no parameters, which
>   is defined without any empty parentheses. Invocations of parameterless
>   functions may not supply parentheses. This supports the uniform access
>   principle, which enables the def to be changed into a val without
>   requiring a change to client code.
>
> A parameterless method is a parameterless function that is a member of
>   a class, trait, or singleton object.